# Help in a proof in Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to understand the end of this proof:

[image]

The theorem 6.1 is:

[image]

I need help in this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose u is a unit. Then there is some v such that uv = 1. Apply deg to both sides of that equality, and work out deg u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\in F[x]$ is a unit, then $f$ is non-zero because $F[x]$ is not the trivial ring, and of course by definition there is some $g\in F[x]$ such that $fg=1$. The latter fact, by Theorem 6.1(iv), implies
$$\deg(f)+\deg(g)=\deg(fg)=\deg(1)=0.$$
For any non-zero $h\in F[x]$, we have $\deg(h)\geq 0$, so the above forces $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=0$, i.e. $f$ and $g$ must both have been constants. Hence any unit $f$ is a non-zero constant.

Comment: thank you very much, very complete answer!